# MySQL + PHP - Querying relative format dates

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, php-carbon

I have two tables: *steps* and *flows*.

- steps has many flows.
- steps has `relative_time` (string) column.
- flows has `active_on` (nullable, timestamp) column.

Steps `relative_time` stores [relative formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) and their values looks like: "+1 year", "+2 days", "+30 days", etc.

Flows `active_on` is set when a flow gets activated by user and it looks like: "2017-12-30 00:00:00".

Every time I want to know when a *flow* will expire, I select it from database and, in PHP (Laravel, [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)), I execute:

```
/**
 * @return null|Carbon
 */
public function getExpiresAtAttribute() 
{
    if (!$this->active_on) {
        return null;
    }

    // Access the relative time for step (for example: "+3 days").
    $relativeTime = $this->step->relative_time;

    // Adds the limit time to the activation date,
    // turning it possible to check when the current flow
    // will "expires". 
    return $this->active_on->modify($relativeTime);        
}
```

**Problem**

It's easy to check expires at value in PHP. The problem is that now I need to select only flows that are "expired" directly from database and I don't know if it is possible by using this approach. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can use STR_TO_DATE() (http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-str_to_date/) to transform a string to a date, then do a select where NOW() > your_date for example

Comment: @MickaelLeger can you give me a practical query example considering the described relative formats?

Comment: Just thinking but can't you add some `active_off` column too? For example if you have `relative_time = +1 year` and you create some `active_on = "2018-09-09 00:00:00"` you create some `active_off = "2019-09-20 00:00:00"` and the SELECT part should be easy?

Comment: If you show us the query you have written, we can make sensible suggestions on how to add `str_to_date()` to that query

Comment: Why downvote???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store in relative_time the number of days, instead of the php date interval. This way you can query:

```
SELECT * FROM flows, steps WHERE flows.step_id = step.id AND NOW() > ADDDATE(flows.active_on, steps.relative_time)
```

This way you get all the flows expired.

No need to change database structure actually. You could create a migration to transform relative_time from dateinterval to number of days (is a string field).

```
foreach (Steps::all() as $step) {
    $step->update([
      'relative_time' => strtotime($step->relative_time,0)/(3600*24);
    ]);
}
```

Then you can adjust the getExpiresAtAttribute:

```
/**
 * @return null|Carbon
 */
public function getExpiresAtAttribute() 
{
    if (!$this->active_on) {
        return null;
    }

    // Access the relative time for step (for example: "+3 days").
    $relativeTime = $this->step->relative_time;

    // Adds the limit time to the activation date,
    // turning it possible to check when the current flow
    // will "expires". 
    return $this->active_on->modify("+$relativeTime days");        
}
```

Comment: Good idea, but are you sure OP can change the database structure easily?

Comment: @AlexandreThebaldi I have elaborated a bit more the answer

Comment: @DailosMedina Ok, I will think a bit about your proposal!